# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Django)

Tags: django, postgresql

Hola estoy trabajando con el gestor de datos PostgreSQL y Django. Quiero hacer una consulta desde el gestor utilizando una clase la cual ya he importado y trabajando desde el shell, actualmente esta así:

```
class clientes(models.Model):
    primer_nombre=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    segundo_nombre=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    primer_apellido=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    segundo_apellido=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email=models.EmailField()
    telefono=models.CharField(max_length=13)
    contraseña=models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return "El nombre es: %s %s %s %s, su E-mail es: %s, sú teléfono es: %s, su contraseña es: 
            %s" % (self.primer_nombre, self.segundo_nombre, self.primer_apellido, 
            self.segundo_apellido, self.email, self.telefono, self.contraseña)
```

Al momento de hacer la consulta sin el medoto `__str__` funcionaba, pero me daba el ID. Cuando quise ver todo el contenido agregando esta función, al hacer el llamado `clientes.objects.filter(primer_apellido='AP1')` me da el error **TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre que funcionara, cambiando el codigo utilizando la propiedad `.format` y reiniciando el **shell** quedando así la función `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'El nombre es: {} {} {} {}, su E-mail es: {}, sú teléfono es: {}, su 
       contraseña es: {}'.format(self.primer_nombre, self.segundo_nombre, 
       self.primer_apellido, self.segundo_apellido, self.email, self.telefono, 
       self.contraseña)
```